# Выявление неоднородных определений

Tags: синтаксис

Как понять, херактеризуют определения предмет с одной стороны или с разных сторон?

Например: стройная худощавая фигура.

И стройная, и худощавый характеризуют фигуру по её очертаниям, по её внешнему виду.

Но: небрежные, точные, быстрые и красивые движения.

В данном случае тождественность сторон, с которых рассматривается движение, более очевидна?

Comment: Куприн употребляет это сочетание в описании облика Гарина-Михайловского, а затем этот текст приводится в учебнике для 8 класса Тростенцовой, Ладыженской.

Answer (score 3):

> И стройная, и худощавый характеризуют фигуру по её очертаниям, по её внешнему виду.

Да,  конечно, сложновато определить,  но,  посмотрев толкование каждого прилагательного,  все же можно заметить разницу. «Стройный» говорит о пропорциональности фигуры, а «худощавый» — о наличии жира. Во втором примере описывается манера движения.